# Can I do ADO.NET using List<T> or IEnumerable<T> in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ado.net, data-access-layer, data-access

Can I do something similar to this in a .NET Core Class Library?  I'm having trouble adding a reference to System.Data.SqlClient to my .NET Core Class Library and I don't know what to add instead.

```
public static List<Person> GetByLastName(string lastName)
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_myStoredProcedure", connection);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
    SqlDataReader dr = null;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Person person = new Person();

            person.FirstName = dr["Person"].ToString();
            person.LastName = dr["LastName"].ToString();
            person.PersonID = (int)dr["PersonID"];

            people.Add(person);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log Error
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Close();
        if (dr != null && !dr.IsClosed)
            dr.Close();
    }

    return people;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-the-new-microsoftdatasqlclient/) instead for new projects.

Comment: Yep, System.Data.SqlClient is now effectively obsolete.

Comment: You can also skip all that code you wrote by installing Dapper

Comment: You should dispose your objects with `using` blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what it looks like in Dapper:

```
public static List<Person> GetByLastName(string lastName)
{
    using connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
    return connection.Query<Person>("usp_myStoredProcedure", new { lastName }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
}
```

You just need a `[Column(Name = "Person")]` on your C# Person's `FirstName` property

(And add some error handling if you want - omitted for brevity)